# How to view tree of library files loaded at runtime by Python program in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, shared-libraries, dependency-walker

In Windows, the **[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)** tool shows a tree of DLLs that is loaded by an executable.

In a similar way, is it possible to know the **tree** of all the **shared libraries** (`*.so`) that are loaded by a Python program when I run it in **Linux**?

Comment: You mean `python -v`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I did not know that! :-D That's a good start, but it seems to give only the first level of the tree. In any case make it a answer, so others can improve it :-)

Comment: Once the program is running as pid 1234, type `cat /proc/1234/maps` ....